# deploy automatically file to tomcat from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a VPS which I can access via `myvm.com` My tomcat location is `C:\tomcat\`
I can access my web application thats inside my tomcate/WebApps folder via `http://myvm.com`

Now I have a java project at `C:\MyProject`. I have imporeted my project into eclipse. Now I want as soon as I edit some file in C:\MyProject, it should automatically deploy it to C:\tomcat so that I can browse it via http://myvm.com

How to do that? Please some detailed steps I am very new to this system.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you :
[tuto eclipse tomcat](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html)

If you declare your tomcat installation (in C:\tomcat) in your eclipse installation, you should be able to auto publish in it or at least using "redeploy" command

Comment: how to tell eclipse about C:\tomcat?

Comment: when you add your tomcat adapter he will ask you where your tomcat installation is located on your system

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) to keep your tomcat updated with the latest changes to your java project.

The jvm doesn't support some kinds of hotreplacement code but you can use [DCEVM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) to overpass them:

> The Dynamic Code Evolution Virtual Machine (DCE VM) is a modification of the Java HotSpot(TM) VM that allows unlimited redefinition of loaded classes at runtime. The current hotswapping mechanism of the HotSpot(TM) VM allows only changing method bodies. Our enhanced VM allows adding and removing fields and methods as well as changes to the super types of a class.